# Typescript error showing up when update method for state element by using React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with Typescript and want to add uid to dataId array.
this is my code.

```
type ElementData = {
  uid: string;
  description: string;

}

const Modal:React.FC<Props>= (props) => {
  const [chipsState, setChipsState] = useState(false);
  const [dataId, setDataId] = useState([]);
  
  const onChipClick = (element:ElementData) => {
   setChipsState(chipsState => !chipsState);  
   setDataId(dataId　=> [...dataId , element.uid]);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

in this case, the following error show up with `setDataId(dataId　=> [...dataId , element.uid])` here.

```
Argument of type '(dataId: never[]) => string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(dataId: never[]) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Please help me to fix this error. Thank you.

Comment: What's the type of `setDataId`? Also are you aware that in `setDataId(dataId　=> [...dataId , element.uid])` you're taking an **argument named `dataId`** - which overwrites the binding to `dataId` outside. So the `dataId` you have inside this callback is **not the same as the one outside**. Is the callback to `setDataId` even supposed to take an argument?

Comment: Also note that `[]` has type `never[]`, you may want to type that more strictly using `as`

Comment: oh, I did mistake. changed ```setDataId(preveId => [...preveId , element.uid])```. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your initial state is an empty array so TS cannot infer type of `dataId` as array of strings, you can define type of state as:

```
const [dataId, setDataId] = useState<string[]>([]);
```